# How do I get the path to script calling a method in another script?

Tags: php, oop

**How do I get the path to a script that is calling a method of a class defined in another script, from *within* the class?**

That is, I'd like to make a call to a class method - defined in `b.php` - from `a.php` as:

**PHP code**

```
# a.php

require 'b.php';

$obj = new AsyncDecorator('ClassName');
$obj->Call('methodName');
```

... with, as previously mentioned, the class being defined in `b.php` similarly to this snippet:

**PHP code**

```
# b.php

class AsyncDecorator
{
    public function Call($method)
    {
        # Currently equals to b.php - I need it to be 'a.php'
        $require = __FILE__;
    }
}
```

That is, I need to know that the calling script was `a.php`, and I need to do it dynamically. If I'm creating and using the `AsyncDecorator` class in `c.php`, then `$require` should equal to `'c.php'`.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to this problem is making either the `Call()` method, or the initialization of the decorator to accept a `$file_path` parameter in which `__FILE__` is passed:

**PHP code**

```
$obj = new AsyncDecorator('ClassName', __FILE__);
$obj->Call('methodName');
```

This has the minor downside of requiring the file path to be passed each time this object is created, which might add unnecessary parameters and not keep its use as simple and **seamless** as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gist here](https://gist.github.com/hamstar/1122679) with a function to get the calling class.

Comment: I greatly appreciate, but I'm looking for the calling ***script***. Is it possible that `debug_backtrace()` holds the key to my enlightenment?

Comment: Yes, class is just one value. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php.